# Nokia apps Development

Tags: nokia

I want to develop the Nokia Apps. How to start? Where to start? Where will I get the details information ? What are the dev environment they supporting?

Please help me.. Thanks in advance.

I am a fresher to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some existing frameworks that are old, but Nokia is strongly pushing their new product Qt (ok, not so new now :), they bought the company who was developing it some time ago). So, in their opinion Qt will be used in more and more of their phones, and it's my suggestion you start there, since it's the 'new stuff', and there will probably be more and more contests for apps where you can publish you app and use it as a reference (if you're going seriously about this).

Don't be confused about Qt - it's designed to be used both to develop desktop and embedded apps. I'm guessing you're going for mobile, so look out for Qt Mobility pack since it contains most of the code you'll probably use (it's a library for Qt that has mobile-common functionality)

There are some resources you'll find on the net, but for start see [here](http://qt.nokia.com/), and you can easily build up from there with googleing ;-)

Good luck!

**edit:** Now that the time has passed, I have to say that things have changed - the qt is being dropped in favor of the microsoft's phone sdk... once it gets out that is :)

Comment: Hi, What about the SymbianC++ for developing app? Could you please share you views?

Comment: Sorry, haven't used it :( but my suggestion is when evaluating what to use, first check it's prospects...